# Change the structure of my array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'd like to change the structure of my result.There are objects "itemGroup" and I'd like to delete them and keep keys "fruit" and "vegetable".

```
[{"id": 1, "shop": "shop1", "itemGroup": {"fruit": 2, "vegetable": 2},"total":4},
    {"id": 2, "shop": "shop2", "itemGroup": {"fruit": 0, "vegetable": 1},"total":1}]
```

I'd like this result

```
[ 
{ "id": 1, "shop": "shop1", "fruit": 2, "vegetable": 2, "total": 4 }, 
{ "id": 2, "shop": "shop2" "fruit": 0, "vegetable": 1, "total": 1 } 
]
```

my code

```
var myArray = [
{shop: "shop1",item1: "my apple 1",item2: "my carrot 1"},
{shop: "shop1",item1: "my apple 1",item2: "my carrot 1"},
{shop: "shop2",item1: "my apple 0",item2: "my carrot 0"},
{shop: "shop2",item1: "my apple 0",item2: "my carrot 1"}
];

var MyArrayDefinition = [
{item: "my apple 0",color: "red", group: "fruit",score: 0},
{item: "my carrot 1",color: "orange",group: "vegetable",score: 1},
{item: "my apple 1",color: "red", group: "fruit",score: 1},
{item: "my carrot 0",color: "orange",group: "vegetable",score: 0}
];

var k = Object.keys,
items = MyArrayDefinition.reduce((o, v) => (o[v.item] = v, o), {});

var shops = myArray.reduce((o, v, i, s) => (
                s = v[k(v).find(k => k)],
                s = o[s] || (o[s] = {
                    fruit: 0,
                    vegetable: 0,
                            }),
                k(v).forEach(k => k.includes('item') &&
                    (s[(i = items[v[k]]).group] += i.score)), o), {});

            var result = k(shops).map((k, i) => ({
                id: i + 1,
                shop: k,
                itemGroup: shops[k],
                total:Object.values(shops[k]).reduce((a, b) => a + b),
            }));
```

Comment: Count each type, divide by the total, multiply by 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expounding on your "original question" set the percentages of each item in the store, and answering your "modified question" change the structure of my array, this gives you both by modifying your original code.

```
let myArray = [{"shop":"shop1","item1":"my apple 1","item2":"my carrot 1"},{"shop":"shop1","item1":"my apple 1","item2":"my carrot 1"},{"shop":"shop2","item1":"my apple 0","item2":"my carrot 0"},{"shop":"shop2","item1":"my apple 0","item2":"my carrot 1"}]
let MyArrayDefinition = [{"item":"my apple 0","color":"red","group":"fruit","score":0},{"item":"my carrot 1","color":"orange","group":"vegetable","score": null},{"item":"my apple 1","color":"red","group":"fruit","score":1},{"item":"my carrot 0","color":"orange","group":"vegetable","score":0}]

let k = Object.keys
let items = MyArrayDefinition.reduce((o, v) => (o[v.item] = v, o), {})

let shops = myArray.reduce(function (o, v, i, s) {
  return s = v[k(v).find(function (k) {
    return k;
  })], s = o[s] || (o[s] = {
    fruit: 0,
    vegetable: 0
  }), k(v).forEach(function (k) {
    return k.includes('item') && (s[(i = items[v[k]]).group] += i.score);
  }), o;
}, {});

// Helper function that calculates percentage
function percentage (amount, total) {
  if (total === 0) { // added check for 0 divisor
    return `0%`
  }
  return `${(amount / total) * 100}%`
}

let result = k(shops).map((k, i) => {
  let total = Object.values(shops[k]).reduce((a, b) => a + b) | 0 // added check if number else 0
  let fruit = shops[k].fruit | 0 // added check if number else 0
  let veg = shops[k].vegetable | 0 // added check if number else 0
  return {
    id: i + 1,
    shop: k,
    fruit: fruit,
    vegetable: veg,
    total: total,
    fruitPercentage: percentage(fruit, total),
    vegetablePercentage: percentage(veg, total)
  }
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))
/** result from console.log()
 *
   [
     {
       "id": 1,
       "shop": "shop1",
       "fruit": 2,
       "vegetable": 2,
       "total": 4,
       "fruitPercentage": "50%",
       "vegetablePercentage": "50%"
     },
     {
       "id": 2,
       "shop": "shop2",
       "fruit": 2,
       "vegetable": 0,
       "total": 2,
       "fruitPercentage": "100%",
       "vegetablePercentage": "0%"
     }
   ]
 * */
```

Comment: for the some keys, when the value is 0, it displays "NaN".

Comment: Added checks to catch NaN and null values and change them to zero.  Also added a catch to return 0 if the divisor is 0 inside of the percentage function

Comment: My code doesn't works in IE because the javascript synthax .reduce / .find / .includes are note recognized

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much like in most of your questions from the last couple of days. :-)

You can map over the data, use Object.assign and delete the itemGroup.

```js
let x = f.map(e => {
  e = Object.assign(e, e.itemGroup);
  delete e.itemGroup;
  return e;
})

console.log(x);
```

```html
<script>
let f = [{
    "id": 1,
    "shop": "shop1",
    "itemGroup": {
      "fruit": 2,
      "vegetable": 2
    },
    "total": 4
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "shop": "shop2",
    "itemGroup": {
      "fruit": 0,
      "vegetable": 1
    },
    "total": 1
  }
]
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using map is the way to transpose the data from one array onto another and run calculations if needed.

```
// Create a function that takes in your result array
function setPercentage (array) {

  // Helper function that calculates percentage
  function percentage (amount, total) {
    return (amount / total) * 100
  }

  // Map the results of the input array onto a new array,
  // and return the result
  return array.map((obj) => {
    return {
      id: obj.id,
      shop: obj.shop,
      fruit: percentage(obj.itemGroup.fruit, obj.total),
      vegetable: percentage(obj.itemGroup.vegetable, obj.total),
      total: obj.total
    }
  })

}

// pass in the result array from your code...
const shops_by_percentage = setPercentage(result)


console.log(shops_by_percentage)

/** result in the console.log()
 *
   [
     {
       'id': 1,
       'shop': 'shop1',
       'fruit': 50,
       'vegetable': 50,
       'total': 4
     },
     {
       'id': 2,
       'shop': 'shop2',
       'fruit': 0,
       'vegetable': 100,
       'total': 1
     }
   ] 
 *
 * */
```

Answer (score 0):

Below you can find general solution to your problem.

Using this approach you can create unlimited number of items in your items array as well as unlimited number of groups in your definitions and your code will still work as expected. Lastly your score value acts as weight (when you give some item for example score 2 each occurrence will count as two items).

```js
// Your items
const items = [
  {
    shop: "shop1",
    item1: "my apple 1",
    item2: "my carrot 1",
  },
  {
    shop: "shop1",
    item1: "my apple 1",
    item2: "my carrot 1"
  },
  {
    shop: "shop2",
    item1: "my apple 0",
    item2: "my carrot 0"
  },
  {
    shop: "shop2",
    item1: "my apple 0",
    item2: "my carrot 1"
  },
];

// Your definitions
const definitions = [
  {
    item: "my apple 0",
    color: "red",
    group: "fruit",
    score: 0
  },
  {
    item: "my carrot 1",
    color: "orange",
    group: "vegetable",
    score: 1
  },
  {
    item: "my apple 1",
    color: "red",
    group: "fruit",
    score: 1
  },
  {
    item: "my carrot 0",
    color: "orange",
    group: "vegetable",
    score: 0
  }
];

function groupShops(items) {
  return items.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    // Find shop with id of current item in accumulator
    const currentShop = acc.find(shop => shop.id === cur.shop);
    
    // Get all shop items
    const shopItems = Object.keys(cur)
      // Filter shop key as it is shop's ID
      .filter(key => key !== 'shop')
      // Map keys into values
      .map(key => cur[key]);
    
    // If shop already exists in accumulator
    if (!!currentShop) {
      // Return updated accumulator
      return acc
        // Remove current shop
        .filter(shop => shop !== currentShop)
        // And add new copy of current shop with new items to the accumulator
        .concat({
          id: currentShop.id,
          items: currentShop.items.concat(shopItems),
        });
    }
    
    // If shop doesn't exist in accumulator add it there and return updated accumulator
    return acc.concat({
      id: cur.shop,
      items: shopItems,
    });
  }, []);
};

function extendItems(shops) {
  // Filter items which have score 0 or less
  const filterItems = items => items.filter(item => item.score > 0);
  
  // Map though shops
  return shops.map(shop => {
    // Return updated shop
    return {
      // Keep shop id
      id: shop.id,
      // Extend itemIds by the properties stored in the definition and filter them
      items: filterItems(shop.items.map(item => definitions.find(definition => definition.item === item))),
    }
  });
}

function calculateResult(shop, index) {
  // Get all available groups
  const availableGroups = definitions.reduce((acc, cur) => acc.indexOf(cur.group) > -1 ? acc : acc.concat(cur.group), []);
  
  // Calculate total possible score
  const getTotalScore = () => shop.items.reduce((acc, cur) => cur.score + acc, 0);
  
  // Get score of a passed group
  const getGroupScore = group => shop.items.reduce((acc, cur) => cur.group === group ? acc + cur.score : acc, 0);
  
  // Loop though each available group and get its score
  const resultData = availableGroups.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    return {
      // Copy data from accumulator
      ...acc,
      // Add new property to the accumulator with a property key {group name} and value {percantage}
      [cur]: getGroupScore(cur, shop.items) / getTotalScore(shop.items) * 100,
    }
  }, {});
  
  // Return result object
  return {
    // Destruct items of the result object 
    ...resultData,
    // Store total items count
    total: shop.items.length,
    // Store shop id
    shop: shop.id,
    // Store index
    id: index,
  }
}

// Groups shops
const groupedShops = groupShops(items);

// Groups shops with extended items
const extendedShops = extendItems(groupedShops);

// You result object
const result = extendedShops.map((shop, index) => calculateResult(shop, ++index));

console.log(result);
```